# Assistance working with Files in Python 3

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently taking an introduction class to python scripting and am in need of help. The below variables are given

```
The file name -> P = test.txt
firstname -> F = 'Ruthy'
lastname -> L = 'Anderson'
new birthday-> B = 00000000
```

The objective is to search the file for the given first and last name and then replace the current birthday that is there with the 'B' variable. We are told that each record has a fixed length of 40.

Below is what the test.txt file contains

Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore        Anderson        03201990Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980Adam            Smithers        11111900Ruthy           Anderson        06062010

This is the code that I have thus far.

```
file1 = open(P, 'r')
data = file1.read()
file1.close()
file2 = open(P, 'w')
recordLength = 40
start = 0
records = []

while((len(data) - start) >= recordLength):
 record = data[start:start + recordLength]
 records.append(record)
 start+= recordLength

for i in range(0, len(records)):
 if re.seatch(F, data) and re.search(L, data):
  data = re.sub('10101960', B, data)

file2.write(data)
file2.close()
```

Comment: Please @Koolwhip, review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
You should add a verifiable example of what you tried. 
If not it will be flagged as OFF-TOPIC. 
Read point 3 on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -> 
Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Also, please create a minimum verifiable example with the input data, etc. Please, help us to help you.

Comment: My apologies for the lack of information. I have updated the post, hopefully it gives you all everything you need. Please let me know what else is needed.

Comment: IMO if your records are of fixed length, this would give you the opportunity to change the data in the file inplace as you know exactly where which kind of data is stored. Also you didn't format your example as code - are there linebreaks between the records?

Comment: @koolwip. here 2 points to check:

You say each record has 40 chars. But in fact:

Adam Smith 11111985 <- 19 chars
Theodore Anderson 03201990 <- 27
Monty Biscuit-Barrel 10181980 <- 29
Adam Smithers 11111900 <-- 22
Ruthy Anderson 06062010 <-- 23

As you see, there is no fixed line. 

In the other hand, are you sure that the file does not contain more than one line?? Are you sure you did unix/windows conversions for CR/LF or similar?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC my approach would be the following:

```
# P = 'test.txt'
# F = 'Ruthy'
# L = 'Anderson'
# B = '00000000'

with open(P, 'r+') as f:
    while True:
        rec = f.read(40)
        if rec:
            if rec.startswith(f'{F} {L}'):
                pos = f.tell()
                f.seek(pos-8)
                f.write(B)
                break
        else:
            break
```